# C# Create list of generic functions

Tags: c#, .net, func

I want to create a list of functions that would accept class variables of any type. Something like this. But I do not know how I can achieve this.

1. Is this the correct way to declare generic function that would take in class variables?
2. How can I add generic function to return a list? I have tried below but that does not help either

`public List<MyFunction<T>> GetMyFunctionList<T>() where T : struct, TextFragment`

```
public class MyFunction<T>
{
    public MyFunction(Func<T, string> functionName)
    {
        this.FunctionName = functionName;
    }

    public Func<T, string> FunctionName { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    int var1;
    Bar var2;
    
    public MyClass (int var1, Bar var2)
    {
        this.var1 = var1;
        this.var2 = var2;
    }
    
    public List<MyFunction> getMyFunctionList(){
        return new List<MyFunction> // throws error - "using generic type returns one type argument
        {
            this.Foo1(var1),
            this.Foo2(var2)
        }
    }
    
    public MyFunction<int> Foo1(int var1)
    {
        return new MyFunction((i) => {
            int res =  var1*2; 
            return res.ToString()
        })
    }
    
    public MyFunction<Bar> Foo2(Bar var2)
    {
        return new MyFunction((i) => {
            return var2.ToString() + " value"; 
        })
    }       
}
```

Comment: How do you intend on using the list returned by `getMyFunctionList`? You can't safely call any of the functions inside it, can you? You don't know what type of parameter _any_ of them needs.

Comment: Can I modify the function so that it can accept data type?

Comment: You can, but I guess the use case doesn't really make sense. What would it do if given the wrong type? Throw an exception? Try to convert? It looks like really `MyFunction` needs to store its own typed value, is that correct?

Comment: @Charlieface, I am not following. Foo1() will only accept int and Foo2 will always accept Bar.

Comment: `new List<MyFunction>{this.Foo1(var1)...` seems to indicate that those constructed `MyFunction`s always return the same value based on what you give to the constructor, you don't need to pass new values to them every time. So `MyFunction` looks like it needs to store that value in a field for it to work on to get the result, that way you won't need to worry about the generic parameter except at the constructor

Comment: If datatype is a concern, can I overload MyFunction class in anyway so that it can know the parameter type?

Comment: @Charlieface, ```List<MyFunction> getMyFunctionList()``` is throwing an error - "Using generic type MyFunction requires 1 type argument". Can you give me an example?

Comment: I guess I don't really understand why `MyFunction` has a parameter at all, you don't use it (the `i` variable in each lamda). Instead the lambdas are closing over the `var1` and `var2` variables. Either you want to pass in a parameter on every invocation, or you want to pass in a parameter when you construct each `MyFunction`. Which of those is true?

Comment: @Charlieface, thanks! I guess that was what I was missing. I removed the i variable and made MyFunction non-generic. :)

Comment: If you wanted the other option, one way to do it is to have a non-generic `MyBaseFunction` which is the abstract base class, and `MyFunction` takes the `T` value in its parameter. This means you only need to know the type of `T` when you call the constructor.